# Use backward compatibly in fingerprint API - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am building a password-keeping app. When you open the app, there is a button that says authenticate. When you click it, it should open a fingerprint scan prompt. Since biometrics is only available on Android 6 and above, I chose API level 24 as that seemed enough. But I if I use BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder, it says that it is only for devices after API Level 28. How to support both of these devices without depreciation errors?

Comment: Use the implementation in [the androidx biometrics library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt) instead, unless you want to have two different code paths that uses either `BiometricPrompt` or `FingerprintManager` depending on the OS version.

Comment: Thanks it worked